# And again, how to handle a huge collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, collections

The first part of my 'task' was to find all addends ([partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))) of a number (in my case 365) with all possible permutations of those sequences.

For example: for number 3 we have three possible addend sequences (3) (1;2) (1;1;1) but my method gives (3) (1;2) (2;1) (1;1;1) as I needed.

```
IEnumerable<int[]> SplitAddends(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        var part = SplitAddends(n - i);
        foreach (var array in part) {
            var newArray = new int[array.Length + 1];
            newArray[0] = i; 
            Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 1, array.Length);

            yield return newArray;
        }
    }
    yield return new []{n};        
}
```

This method gives a result in less than 1 ms and it's correct. The problem is the second part of this task. I need to do some calculations with each element.
For example:

```
void ExampleMethod(int N) {
    var partition = SplitAddends(N); // < 1ms execution time
    foreach (var variant in partition) { // problematic line
        var someResult = 0f;
        foreach (var item in variant) {
            someResult += SomeEquation(item);
        }
        SendToCompare(someResult);
    }
}
```

It takes several seconds for numbers like 15-25 (for N=20 partition has 524288 sequences) and it takes hours for numbers like 35-50.

I've already tried things like `Parallel.ForEach`, `while(partition.MoveNext())` and changing the type of collection. Even `partition.Count()` takes years for execution.

I know about one workaround for that. The calculations may be put inside of `SplitAppends` method and be executed in a top layer of stack but this way seems tricky.

Comment: We cant optimize a story, and incidentally not going to read a wiki on number theory and write you an algorithm (in the most part) . If you are truly interested in answers, you need an [mcve]. However likely you would be better off taking this to CodeReview unless you have specific concerns about a particular set of optimizations. Once again, you will need an [mcve]

Comment: Secondly, you need to be confident your actual algorithm is the most efficient solution to start with. Maybe you can try MathOverflow

Comment: @TheGeneral My friend. Especially for you dotnetfiddle.net/ukdcYF . This is the code from my post (without extra lines). Long story short - read the title. You don't need to know/read maths for answering that question. And yes, I'm absolutely sure that this (Turing Machine) is the only way to solve my whole problem. I could explain it as a creator but no need.

Comment: For those who wanna try the actual problem. You have APY formula for periodic compounds. Now suggest that you can compound any time (every second) but each compound costs a fixed price. You know your TVL value, daily profit (%), and fee price. Calculate the best compound scenario for several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. The 'yield' doesn't give me any result at the time when the method is called. Only when I'm using the yielding elements. That's why this method is finished in 1 ms and 'foreach' takes so long. And the problem has ~O(2^N) difficulty, that's why we can't use if for N=360.